# Has Japanese syntax changed between the 1950s and today?

Tags: language-evolution

Excluding vocabulary items which are entirely new or have fallen into disuse, what are some ways in which Japanese syntax itself has changed between the 1950s and today?

(I would also like to exclude phenomena such as the semi-productivity of terms like ググる, since I'd argue these are new vocabulary and not fully productive ways of deriving new words.)

Comment: This is a very interesting question, and I'd like to see good answers to it. +1 But I think save academic sources it may be hard to solicit good answers because of the sheer complexity of the issue. I think it's safe to say English syntax in use has changed quite a bit since the 1950s (I'd say even since the early 2000s)

Comment: This was actually the impetus for my question. I know certainly as an English speaker that English syntax has changed somewhat over the past fifty years, but thinking back over my study of Japanese, I couldn't bring up any examples of syntactic language change over the same period of time.

Comment: Syntax ≠ vocabulary.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax.

Comment: You can start with [JACAR's brief summary](https://www.jacar.go.jp/glossary/tochikiko-henten/qa/qa23.html) with references at the end of the page. That "English" button tho...

Comment: What is meant by 'English syntax has changed'? There may be some outdated constructions, but generally 19th century novels' English looks modern enough to me. Or you are asking for words that are still in use but in a different sense now compared with 50 years ago?

Comment: @sundowner Consider constructions like "Have you any money?" or "I shall tell him tomorrow, lest he invite the whole family." English syntax _has_ changed, at least when it comes to the conversational register.

Comment: [This](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E4%B9%B1%E3%82%8C) may be of interest. My impression is that it hasn't changed a lot in terms of ("pure") constructions. One  thing that comes to my mind is the expression/construction used e.g. by a waitress at ファミレス: Xでよろしかったでしょうか?  which got common since some time in 2000s(?).

Comment: Would you also exclude the recent adjective-like use of the verb 違う, like 違くて, 違くない, etc?

Comment: @aguijonazo This is new to me, and I'm unsure how "accepted" it is (even among the youth). It seems pretty hard to stomach... https://mainichi-kotoba.jp/blog-20200502

Comment: But I kind of understand why people expect 違う to behave like an adjective. Japanese has no adjective that means “different” (at least not an easy one suitable for everyday usage) when we do have 同じ for the opposite meaning.

Comment: For now, I personally think ちがくて and きれくて are pure irregularities at the vocabulary level. I don't think many people will start saying 合くて (instead of 合って) or 嫌くて (instead of 嫌いで) in the foreseeable future.

Comment: @sundowner I wanted to respond to your question about why some of us claim English syntax has changed: if a native speaker of American English in their 50s were to pay careful attention to how American teens speak these days, I imagine they'd find it highly irregular. I think there are some very noticeable tendencies, like article dropping. IMHO the English(es) spoken by native speakers in the UK and the US are being influenced heavily by non-native speakers, during virtual interaction online becoming the social norm. A lot of non-native speakers are highly fluent with native sounding accents.

Comment: (cont'd) Their English may not be 100% perfect, syntax wise. But exactly because of their near perfect accents and their high fluency--as a result of them interacting with native speakers all the time online--they in turn influence native speaking teens who seem to have picked up things from non-native speakers. Yes, IMHO English is being shaped and  reshaped by non-native speakers. One of the things--there's a ton I could talk about, just an example--is how articles and prepositions get dropped. Now I sometimes hear monolingual American/British teens say, "I'm from USA" "I live in UK".

Comment: Those are of course incorrect, grammatically speaking. It should always be "the USA" and "the UK" (the few exceptions being: they appear in headlines or on labels, or attributively). Also prepositions get dropped or swapped around a lot in modern teenspeak and transitive verbs become intransitive, intransitive transitive, and so on. "search it up" "chat me" "guess on" etc.

Comment: There was a typo: not "during virtual interaction online" -->"due to virtual interaction online"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[言文一致](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genbun_itchi) and the shift to modern kana orthography (1946) happened shortly before this period, and they were undoubtedly much more fundamental than anything that happened after 1950. But I'll focus on the change of modern 口語 here. The list is far from complete; I just wrote down things that came to mind.

- Decline of ましょう as a way to express future inference.

  > 明日は雨が降りましょう。

  This was common in weather forecast until the 1970's, but we never hear this today. See: https://ameblo.jp/heppokomental/entry-12527905042.html
- Decline of some "heavy" keigo patterns (でございます, でありました, くださいませ, ...)
- Continued decline of ぬ as a negation marker (ありませぬ, 分からぬ, ...)
- Decline of many gender-specific sentence endings (かしら, だわ, ...), although many remain in fictional works as part of お嬢様言葉
- Decline of most iteration marks (ゝ, [〱](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40805/5010), ...) except 々. (If I understand correctly, these symbols have never been officially standardized nor banned by the government.)
- Increased acceptance of ら抜き of ichidan potential forms (食べれる, 見れる, ...)
- Increased acceptance of `i-adjective + です` (嬉しいです, よかったです, ...) and the decline of ～うございます. See: [Conjugating present and past negative i-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68964/5010)

Comment: One of the things I noticed in Japanese textbooks is a lot of new books or new editions ditched ません/ませんでした and ではありません/ではありませんでした in favor of ないです/なかったです and じゃないです/じゃなかったです. The first edition of Genki still only taught ません/ませんでした IIRC.

Comment: @EddieKal Really? I remember learning about ません/ませんでした and ではありません in Genki I third edition.

Comment: @JimmyYang I'm sure it's discussed but like I said, Genki I first edition doesn't even explain ないです. And that's one of the major changes the second edition included.

Comment: @EddieKal Perhaps you're talking about 嬉しく(は)ありませんでした vs 嬉しくなかったです, for example? The latter still sounds "unsophisticated in formal written documents" to me, but I understand it's better as a starter for learners.

Comment: @JimmyYang I can't find the 3rd edition online, but here's how the 1st and 2nd editions differ: (1) 1st ed. pp 37-38: やまださんはがくせいじゃありません and that's the only form taught. 2rd ed. pp 65-66: やまださんはがくせいじゃないです The 2nd ed. only mentions じゃありません・ではありません in passing later.  (2) 1st ed. p80 the past tense of XはYです is taught as present tense じゃありません/past tense じゃありませんでした and makes sure to mention ではありません・ではありませんでした. 2rd ed. p110 the form taught is じゃないです・じゃなかったです. And じゃありません・じゃありませんでした etc. are footnoted. (3) for verbs the 2nd edition mentions なかったです: 帰らなかったです while the 1st doesn't have that part.

Comment: @naruto on negation of adjectives: (4) in the 1st ed. only one form is taught: おもしろくありませんでした (p100); in comparison, the 2nd ed. p132 さむくなかったです, and only mentions さむくありませんでした in a parenthetical.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by "syntax" basic structures of the language and fundamental rules of how you construct a sentence (like the subject-object-verb order), I'd say nothing has changed. Most languages don't change at the fundamental level in 70 years, or in the lifetime of a person.

That said, which grammatical words and constructions are preferred have changed in some cases, especially in spoken Japanese. Off the top of my head, in negation constructions, ないです is a much more acceptable alternative to ありません than it was, and -ぬ (as in 足らぬ) became less preferred over -ない (as in 足りない). You hear less いかに and いかなる for "how" and "what", more どう/どのように and どんな. I'm sure there are many more examples like these. The old words like these can still be spoken, and maybe part of set phrases in some cases, but they generally add an old-fashioned tone to how you speak. (Not too unlike how "thou" and "thee" may sound in English, I think.)

There is a famous song starting with 兎追いしかの山. This would be 兎を追ったあの山 ("the mountain where I chased after rabbits") in today's Japanese. Children learn this song in school and may misunderstand 追いし as 美味し(い), because the 追いし form of the verb 追う is simply not used any more.

Comment: Furusato may not be a good example here. It is a song written in 文語 in 1914, and there *was* a fundamental change in how people write Japanese at that time.

Comment: Perhaps. I admit I don't know how children in 1950 would have perceived the lyrics, although I imagine people's familiarity with 文語 would have gradually decreased over time, including the period between 1950 and now.